# Deserialize to self

Tags: c#, serialization, object

Ok, I'm probably just having an epic fail here, but my mind wants to say this should work.

Assume DataProtect.DecryptData takes an encrypted string as input and a decrypted string as output. Assume deserializeXML makes the appropriate object and returns it from the newly decrypted string.

So. Why wouldn't this work?

```
class ArrivedDetails
{
///...

    internal ArrivedDetails(string encrypted)
    {
        this = DataProtect.deserializeXML(DataProtect.DecryptData(encrypted));
    }
///...
```

Gives me an error of

```
Cannot assign to '<this>' because it's read only
```

More specifically,, how can I get this working? I essentially want to decrypt an XML serialized version of the object and then deserialize it within the constructor.

I'm open to "you can't" (with an explanation) as I can put it elsewhere and just assign values, but my mind says something like this should be possible.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, this is not possible using a constructor, you can't reassign `this`.

Use a static method instead:

```
public static ArrivedDetails CreateFromString(string encrypted)
{
    return DataProtect.deserializeXML(DataProtect.DecryptData(encrypted));
}
```

Call it:

```
ArrivedDetails details = ArrivedDetails.CreateFromString(encrypted);
```

Comment: Though I would agree with dotalchemy that the original concept should work, a static method does the trick. I like that you are not instantiating a new object and just returning it.

Comment: This does not deserialize to <this>, does it?

Answer (score 7):

You can archive this with reflection as follows.

```
var tmp = DataProtect.deserializeXML(DataProtect.DecryptData(encrypted));
foreach (var property in GetType().GetProperties())
    if (property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (XmlIgnoreAttribute), false).GetLength(0) == 0)
        property.SetValue(this, property.GetValue(tmp, null), null);
```

This assigns the deserialized object to a temporal variable, and copy the value in each public property to `this` with reflection. This snippet avoids to copy properties with the XmlIgnore attribute.

Answer (score 3):

You can not assign anything to "this".  Change ArriveDetails to a static that return the deserialised object.

```
class ArrivedDetails
{
    static ArrivedDetails Create(string encrypted)
    { return DataProtect.deserializeXML(...) }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a static factory method that creates the object you require.

```
class ArrivedDetails
{
///...

    public static ArrivedDetails CreateFromEncryptedKey(string encrypted)
    {
        return DataProtect.deserializeXML(DataProtect.DecryptData(encrypted));
    }
///...
```

The reason your initial approach didn't work is because `this` is a private read-only instance field that returns the object from which it is called. You can't write to `this`.