# Get abstract class by string name

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two classes:

```
  class Car<T>
{
    public string color { get; set; }
    public virtual T features { get; set; }
    public virtual void TestDrive();
}
class Toyota : Car<ToyotaFeatures>
{
    public override ToyotaFeatures features { get; set; }
    public override void TestDrive()
    {
        //Logic here...
    }
}
```

Now i have a full string class name: "MySol.MyProj.Toyota"
I want to instantiate a class by my string name and then run TestDrive().
The problem is that when I try to run `Activator.CreateInstance(null, "MySol.MyProj.Toyota");`
I cannot cast it to a base class and run testDrive because it is expecting ToyotaFeatures class to be passed to it.  but I just want to run TestDrive() only having a string class name.

And I don't want to cast it to specific type. only to base type so it can decide which TestDrive() to run based on the provided string.

Comment: Why do you want to cast the instance to the base class? Don't you want to run the TestDrive method on your instance? E.g., myInstance.TestDrive()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that purposes interfaces are extra good.

```
interface ITestDrivable
{
    void TestDrive();
}
```

Your abstract class implements the interface:

```
class Car<T> : ITestDrivable
{
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public virtual T Features { get; set; }
    public abstract void TestDrive() { }
}
```

And casting comes very easy:

```
ITestDrivable car = (ITestDrivable)Activator.CreateInstance(null, "MySol.MyProj.Toyota");
car.TestDrive();
```

Comment: That looks awesome. Can you also explain please how do I pass generic dataRow to a constructor so I can populate color and other properties?

Comment: Can I do this inside my derived class? The thing is, I have a generic method, called: convertToObject<T>(DataRow dr) which returns object of myType, but I'm not sure how to use it in my constructor. I was thinking about something like: this = ConvertToObject<Toyota>(dr) but this is not allowed.

Comment: Or maybe I ca do this inside TestDrive(DataRow dr) method somehow.

Comment: @user194076 First of all, you cannot do the `this = something` thing. Because `this` is readonly keyword.

Comment: @user194076 Second, I do not completely understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: What I want to do is, before running TestDrive I need to instantiate an object. and i have a method that returns that object of type T.

Comment: so, in my Toyota I have a constructor Like this: Toyota(DataRow dr) { Toyota t = GetObject<Toyota>(dr); } I can do it manually like this: this.Color = dr["Color"].ToString(); but thought other ways are possible. Ideally I'd like to have a constructor in Car class that automatically casts to a selected derived object

Comment: So, I guess this is not possible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398904/deserialize-to-self and I cannot define factory method because then my interface will be expecting type T for an object and I won't be able to cast generic instance.

Comment: You cannot write in `this` keyword, instead, consider copying all the properties to `this` from some other object.

Answer (score 3):

```
Type type = Type.GetType("MySol.MyProj.Toyota");

var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
type.GetMethod("TestDrive").Invoke(obj, null);
```

Comment: Reflection is slow and should be used when there is **no other way**.

Comment: Is it possible to pass parameters to a constructor this way? do I have to cast to base class

Comment: @user194076 you can pass parameters in an object array (`Activator.CreateInstance(type,new object[]{param1,param2}`) .

Comment: Thanks. I've ended up using interface and your implementation of activator with parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Would that make any sense:

```
abstract class CarFeatures { }

class ToyotaFeatures : CarFeatures { }

abstract class Car
{
    public string color { get; set; }
    public virtual void TestDrive() { }
}

abstract class Car<T> : Car where T : CarFeatures
{
    public virtual T features { get; set; }

    public Car(T _features)
    {
        features = _features;
    }
}

class Toyota : Car<ToyotaFeatures>
{
    public override ToyotaFeatures features { get; set; }

    public Toyota(ToyotaFeatures _features) : base(_features) { }

    public override void TestDrive()
    {
        //Logic here...
    }
}
```

More than once, I derived my generic class from a non-generic one to put all my common methods and fields that were not generic-dependant, giving me an easy access to them.

```
ToyotaFeatures features = new ToyotaFeatures();
Car car = (Car)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Toyota), new object[] { features });
car.TestDrive();
```

However, if someone has a better solution, I would be interrested too.

EDIT: As said above, interface are cool, but my rule of thumb is "Don't create an interface if you use it for only one class". But it works.

RE-EDIT: The problem was instanciating a generic object with a collection of params.

Comment: I cannot cast to Toyota because I only have string name of a class. It can be Honda as well.

Comment: Why would you cast to Toyota if you only want to call TestDrive? Is there a special method in Toyota that you want to access? EDIT: AH! I think I see where you're going with this. You are creating a new object and you're having an hard time populating it's fields on initialization.

Comment: There you go. Activator.CreateInstance allows you to pass the params required by a Constructor. If your base class define a constructor that requires the CarFeatures, you can set them on the creation of your object. From that point, your object should be correctly setup to call its methods.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the interface [IConvertible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible.aspx) in your classes and then use the method [Convert.ChangeType(..)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.changetype.aspx). Code Sample could be:

```
   // hords the created object
   object createdByActivator = ....;
   Car objectAsCar = Convert.ChangeType(createdByActivator, Type.GetType("MySol.MyProj.Toyota"
```

)

Comment: that `Car objectAsCar` thing in your code it his issue. He cannot just write `Car`, its actually `Car<>`, therefore, a generic class.